How to setup /29 uplink from datacenter on Cisco switch
I am colocating and am given a /29 public IP CIDR from my colocation provider.
I have a Cisco Catalyst 3650 24 port managed switch with 4 servers behind it in a VLAN.
How do I setup one of the Gigabit Ethernet interfaces to receive and send traffic to my data center's networking equipment? I can figure out how to assign one IP from that /29 to an interface, but not have that interface act as an uplink to the entire /29 block. There is a way of doing this without needing one interface per IP in the /29, but that's all I have right now.

You likely don't need to do anything. Your provider is probably using one of the IP addresses from the /29 to provide you a gateway address. Configure your servers with the IPs that remain in the /29 and with the correct subnet mask and the gateway address the provider has given you and your servers will be online.
If you want to use a firewall (which is recommended) then you would do that procedure on the firewall and configure any desired network address translation to provide a private network for your servers 'behind' the firewall.
You don't need any VLAN configuration unless the provider has told you to use a specific VLAN or if you have specific reasons to do so for your own network. You don't need another gateway address if your ISP has already provided one and you don't need to further segment your network (you don't have enough IP addresses to really do so very effectively anyway).

Thanks! How should I configure the Gigabit Ethernet interface I plug the colo provided cable into? Do I need to set its switchport mode to trunking or something?

No nothing. Just a regular access mode switch port. For the purposes of connecting a couple of servers to an internet service from a colocation provider, you just take the switch out of the box. Mount it in the rack, plug in your servers and the internet service and turn them all on. That's it.
If you want to do VLANs, management, etc. you need to make a separate question specific to those other topics. For the topic of making servers with with a /29 network from a separate provider, you don't even need a managed switch at all so there is no required configuration for your switch.

Okay thanks I'll make new questions. I do LAG and a IPSec VPN into a management IPMI subnet
